# Memcache or just a static instance per app instance?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a somewhat complex object in my web app, it would take some time to make all its attributes serializable so I could stick it in memcache.

Is there any sense to just keeping it around as a static variable in my web app? I'm not sure how static variables work in app engine. I was thinking of something like this:

```
public class MyServlet {
    private static SpaceShuttle mShuttle;

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) 
        throws IOException 
    { 
        // If the static instance isn't already around in this
        // application instance, build it.
        if (mShuttle == null) {
            // Create it once.
            mShuttle = complexProcessOfCreatingASpaceShuttle();
        }

        // Use it.
        mShuttle.liftOff();
        ...
    }   
}
```

I think memcache would be helpful here since different application instances could share the same object (I think?), but as a temporary fix, at least app instances could share the static instance for the lifetime.

The SpaceShuttle is immutable / read-only so there's no synchronization danger (I think?).

Lots of unknowns here, not sure how app engine works internally. Should I just try making the entire SpaceShuttle serializable?

Thanks

Comment: one more comment - you definitely want to look into configuring warmup requests so that your shuttle object will be created before any users are served by a particular instance (http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig.html#Warming_Requests)

Comment: I've run into a similar problem. Using any lite database is out of the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4663071/a-read-only-relational-database-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on whether the SpaceShuttle object needs to share state between instances.  When running on app engine, your app can have between 0 and many instances running at any given time.  Each instance will look like its own JVM.  (Each instance/JVM might also have multiple threads running within it.)  So as long as your object doesn't need to share state with other instances, you should be fine, and by keeping it around you would be saving your app from having to initialize it for every request.

If your space shuttle objects all need to be synchronized with each other (because they represent some global application state) then you will need some mechanism to keep them in sync, which might be just as annoying as trying to put them in memcache to begin with.

That being said, maybe you can put some of the space shuttle into memcache.  Perhaps you can memcache parts of it, and then grab those when doing the instance specific initialization?

Answer (score -1):

No. This is an issue I see all too often especially on Java web applications -- using persistent static variables are impossible to scale. If it's difficult to serialize the entirety of the SpaceShuttle object, perhaps you can break the problem up and serialize pieces of it?

Comment: It depends on what the shared object is doing.  if it is just a huge lookup table of some sort, or something that only changes once a day, then it is probably just fine.  Each application instance could have its own copy of the object.

Comment: Hi, yes it is just like a big lookup table of sorts that never changes after being loaded. Multiple threads can access it without any issue, its state never changes.